# How transform string dot notation to nested object?

Tags: javascript

I want convert a dot notation string like 'a.b.c.d' to an Object. If the Object doesnt exist I want create a empty one.

```
var str = 'a.b.c.d'
var obj = {}

// so ...

function dotToObj(obj, str) {
    // something 
    obj[?] = obj[?] || {}            
     }

// If object doesnt exist so create a empty object.

var rsp = dotToObj(obj, str);


console.log(rsp)

// Excpect:
Object {a: Object}
    a: Object
        b: Object
            c: Object
                d: Object
                __proto__: Object
            __proto__: Object
        __proto__: Object
    __proto__: Object
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split the string and use the parts for the reference with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), where `obj` is used as the start object and while iterating, the new reference is returned.

```js
var str = 'a.b.c.d',
    obj = {};

str.split('.').reduce(function (r, a) {
    r[a] = r[a] || {};
    return r[a];
}, obj);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: how can I set value for deepest value, example `d = 123`?

Comment: @huykon225, you could take s/t like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55635011/how-to-convert-javascript-array-or-delimited-string-to-an-object-with-sub-obje/55635197#55635197

Comment: That's cool, thank you @Nina Scholz