# JS: dot notation to nested object

Tags: javascript, mongoose, notation

i struggle with this simple function.
My goal is it to parse a dot notated string to a nested object.

An array of this:

```
["image", "groups", "groups.tasks", "groups.image"]
```

Should me give this:

```
[{
        path: "image",
        populate: []
    }, {
        path: "groups",
        populate: [{
                path: "tasks",
                populate: []
            }, {
                path: "image",
                populate: []
            }]
    }]
```

My code so far:

```js
let populate = [];
const query = ["image", "groups", "groups.tasks", "groups.image"];


function parse(str, arr) {


 let c = str.split(".");
 let p = c.shift();

 console.log(c)

 let entry = {
  path: p,
  populate: []
 };


 if (c.length > 0) {

  console.log("Add to '%s'", p, c)
  parse(c.join("."), entry.populate);

 } else {

  arr.push(entry);

 }


}


query.forEach(function (str, index) {

 parse(str, populate);

});

console.log(populate)
```

All i get is the parent array, no childs:

```
[ { path: 'image', populate: [] },
  { path: 'groups', populate: [] } ]
```

I want to use it in a RESTful API where i can populate over nested mongoose documents. The populate array pass i then to the ".populate(...)" function in my express route

e.g:

GET /api/computer?populate=image,groups,group.tasks

There should be no limitation on the deep of nested objects.

By my reaseaches i found this awnser:
[How transform string dot notation to nested object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34899477/how-transform-string-dot-notation-to-nested-object)
But im not sure how to modify it to reach my goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could reduce the array by reducing the splitted path strings.

```js
var array = ["image", "groups", "groups.tasks", "groups.image"],
    result = array.reduce((r, s) => {
        s.split('.').reduce((a, path) => {
            var object = a.find(o => o.path === path);
            if (!object) {
                a.push(object = { path, populate: [] });
            }
            return object.populate;
        }, r);
        return r;
    }, []);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanky you verry much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```js
var aa = ["groups","image","groups.tasks", "groups.image" ]
var result = [];
aa.forEach(element => {

    if (!result.some(a=> a.path === element) && element.indexOf(".") === -1) {
        result.push({ path: element, populate: [] })
    } else {
        if (element.indexOf(".") !== -1) {
            let splittedText = element.split(".");
            if (result.some(a=> a.path === splittedText[0])) {
               var index= result.findIndex(a=> a.path === splittedText[0]);
               result[index].populate.push({ path: splittedText[1], populate: [] });
            }else{
              result.push({ path: splittedText[0], populate: [{ path: splittedText[1], populate: [] }] })              
            }
            
        }
    }
});
console.log(result);
```