# How to convert JavaScript array (or delimited string) to an object with sub-objects

Tags: javascript

I actually wish to convert a string to a deep object, but am pretty sure converting the string to an array is the first step.  Let me explain.

I am using [xeditable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/) which by default will send `{"name": "somePropertyName", "value": "someValue"}` to the server, however, I wish to send  `{"somePropertyName": "someValue"}`.  I am able to accomplish this by setting `$.fn.editable.defaults.params` to the appropriate callback.

Now the part I am stuck on.  I am using a special naming pattern that if the name has periods in it (i.e. name is `a.b.c`), I don't want to send `{"a.b.c": "someValue"}` to the server, but instead send `{"a":{"b":{"c":"someValue"}}}` to the server.

I've got a partially working version, however, it is not very elegant and more importantly I haven't gotten the last property working and have temporarily hardcoded it which is not acceptable.

How can this be accomplished?

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.params = function(params){
    return nvp2obj(params.name, params.value);
}

function nvp2obj(n, v, d) {
    d = d ? d : '.';
    n = n.split('.');
    var o = {};
    var r = o;
    n.reduce(function(total, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
        if(r) {
            r[currentValue]={};
            r=o[currentValue];
        }
        else {
            //this is obviously not correct
            o.a.b.c=v;
        }
        return o;
        }, o);
    return o;
}
var test = nvp2obj('a.b.c', 'someValue'); //{"a":{"b":{"c":"someValue"}}}
console.log('test', JSON.stringify(test));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate the given keys and assign the value by taking the last key.

```js
function setValue(object, keys, value) {
    var last = keys.pop();
        
    keys.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
}

var test = {};
    
setValue(test, 'a.b.c'.split('.'), 'someValue');
setValue(test, 'a.d.e'.split('.'), 'someValue2');
setValue(test, 'a.b.a'.split('.'), 'someValue3');

console.log(test);
```

Comment: `objects` seems unused on your function, object seems to work anyway as it's global.

Comment: This is the best answer by far.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```js
function nvp2obj(n, v, d) {
  n = n.split(d || '.');
  n.reverse()
  return n.reduce(function(res, it) {
    return {[it]: res}
  }, v)
}


var test = nvp2obj('a.b.c', 'someValue');
console.log('test', JSON.stringify(test));

test = nvp2obj('a|b|c', 'someValue', '|');
console.log('test', JSON.stringify(test));
```

Loops through the keys from the end (starts with 'c'), first returning an object with the last key corresponding to the desired value ( `{c: value}` ). Then `{b: {c: value}}`, then `{a: {b: {c: value}}}`

Comment: what happens with the next value?

Comment: You mean if they want to add more keys and values to the same object afterwards as in your code? Not sure, don't think they specified that they need to do that.